# How does mathematica generate FinalPlots

Tags: plotting, graphics, visualization, machine-learning

It is well known that after using `NetTrain[net,dataset,All]`, a `NetTrainResultObject` is returned. This is an association, with a particular key, `FinalPlots` that I am interested in. This shows a plot of the training process of the network, which looks like this:
[image: The FinalPlot]
However, this is not a simple plot of `RoundMeasurements`, and neither does it fit with any of the `PlotTheme` supported by `ListLinePlot`. So where can I find the style and generation process of this graph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From an example in the docs, such data is presented as an association that has plots as Values. There is nothing special about the plots per se.

```
Keys@results["FinalPlots"]
```

> {"Loss", "ErrorRate"}

You can also try `Values@...`.

```
results["FinalPlots"]["ErrorRate"][[1, 1]]
```

(* gives a graph whose `Head` is `Graphics` *)

```
results["FinalPlots"]["ErrorRate"][[1, 1]][[1]]
```

(* gives the Line/Point data to plot as primitives *)

```
Options[results["FinalPlots"]["ErrorRate"][[1, 1]] ]
```

(* provides the options *)

---

For plot themes (extract pts for the line drawn):

```
pts = results["FinalPlots"]["ErrorRate"][[1, 1]][[1, 2, 1, 2, 1]]
```

and apply your theme,

```
ListLinePlot[pts, PlotTheme -> "Scientific"]
```

---

Your question asks "How ... is it generated"? For that I think you can contact their support directly as I cannot readily find it documented, having made a few initial attempts. I am guessing you are referring to the animation etc during the training.